# Stuck on a Monte Carlo Simulation of Confidence Intervals

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I'm trying to run a Monte Carlo simulation to check the coverage of Wald confidence interval, with n=40, p=0.2, and nominal confidence levels of 95%, with 10,000 simulation runs. I need to calculate the empirical coverage. 
I am not sure what I actually need to do to answer. I think I have the majority of it done, but I'm not sure on how to complete it.

```
n <- 40
X <- rbinom(10000, n, 0.2)
pHat <- X/n
a <- 0.05
q <- 1-pHat
k <- qnorm(1-a/2)
#wald CI
waldU <- (X/n)+k*n^(-1/2)*(pHat*q)^(1/2)
waldL <- (X/n)-k*n^(-1/2)*(pHat*q)^(1/2)
```

After running this I have 10,000 upper limits and 10,000 lower limits, should my next step be to average each one?

Comment: Your next step is to calculate the proportion of confidence intervals that cover the true value of p (0.2).

Comment: I think you should add the `self_study` tag.

Comment: Observe that you didn't define  n in your code, it might have been cathed from somewhere else. I ran the code from your post, made hist(pHat), you can clearly see it is wrong. Correct this, then just do as in the other comment with code such as inIC  <-  (waldL < 0.2) & (0.2 < waldU)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, why is the computation of `pHat` wrong? $X$ is Binomial, not Bernoulli. Suppose $X=x$:  if I have $x$ successes out of $n=40$ trials, then clearly the empirical frequency is $\frac{x}{n}$. As a matter of fact, with `set.seed(1)`, we get `mean(pHat)`=0.19991 and `var(pHat)`=0.004071774, which is what you would expect.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by *ocram*, next you need to calculate the proportion of intervals containing the true value

```r
mean(waldL <= p & p <= waldU)
```

where `p` is the true probability of success. Notice that the value of `n` (in `rbinom(nsamples, n, p)`) limits the number of distinct `pHat` values to the set `(1:n)/n`, so with `n` equal to 40 you should not expect exact $100\alpha\%$ coverage, but it should get closer as `n` grows.

---

A coding side-note: *don't* use `x^(1/2)` for square root, use `sqrt` instead. In all (or at least majority) of the programming languages `sqrt` is more computationally efficient then `^(1/2)`, for example a quick benchmark in R shows that it is approximately six times faster:

```r
     test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1 sqrt(x)          500    0.48    1.000      0.37     0.08         NA        NA
2 x^(1/2)          500    2.87    5.979      2.72     0.12         NA        NA
```

Comment: The reason why the Wald interval is undercovering is not only the fact that $n$ is "small" - among the various CIs for a proportion, Wald's is one of those with the worst coverage. And the situation would be even worse if  $p$ were more extreme. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval or one of the many papers on the subject.

Comment: @DeltaIV you are perfectly right, but since `pHat` is defined as  `X/n` it will always be rounded, so the coverage would never be exact (no matter how do you calculate the interval).

Comment: true, not even the so-called "exact" confidence interval has exactly $1-\alpha/2$ coverage. However, there are intervals which have better coverage properties than Wald's: the "exact" CI always overcovers, so it's too conservative, but the Agresti-Coull and the Wilson interval with or without continuity correction, are all preferable to the Wald interval in a vast majority of cases ($(n,p)$ couples).